# MS Graph Rest API Errors

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the following errors for most of the resources in MS Graph. 
Also the same resources are working fine with graph explorer ( https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer ) using dummy tenant.

```
For POST /users
and PATCH /users

Status Code: 403

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
           "request-id": "62c7e8f5-386a-4d15-8e94-5408d81b1383",
            "date": "2017-01-24T09:08:46"
        }
    }
}


GET /drives
GET me/drive

Status Code: 500

{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Unable to resolve template token",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "82ab9b86-7a90-4f86-877a-3ddb03ae1d71",
            "date": "2017-01-24T09:12:35"
        }
    }
}


GET me/messages
GET me/events
GET me/mailFolders
GET me/contacts

Status Code: 504

{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "678af389-cc38-4f5c-9b41-07595e62eee3",
            "date": "2017-01-25T06:48:30"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the list of scopes I have included.

```
"scope": "Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Contacts.Read Contacts.Read.Shared Contacts.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All email Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All Mail.Read Mail.Read.Shared Mail.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send Mail.Send.Shared MailboxSettings.ReadWrite Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.Read.All Notes.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp offline_access openid People.Read profile Sites.Read.All Tasks.Read Tasks.Read.Shared Tasks.ReadWrite Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All"
```