# Error trying to create session on an Excel file using Microsoft Graph

Tags: ruby, excel, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to manipulate an Excel file using Ruby, while I seem to eb able to read it properly - I have trouble creating a session to start writing into it. There's not much help online on what this even means.

I'm trying to create a session like this, just like it suggests on the documentation (but not in ruby)

```
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/#{@item_id}/workbook/createSession"
response = HTTParty.post(url, headers: { 'Authorization' => @access_token, 
           'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 
           body: '{ "persistChanges" : true }')
```

But I get the following response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "EditModeCannotAcquireLockUnknownUser",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b088abbe-8353-4614-b9a7-d769ff85da50",
      "date": "2017-08-15T17:12:41"
    }
  }
}

@response=#<Net::HTTPConflict 409 Conflict readbody=true>
```

I've just started with this, what could be the problem? the error indicates that some unknown user has locked the file - but the file is editable and the access_token is derived from my own user profile

Where do I go from here? has anybody manipulated excel files and formula using Microsoft Graph?

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to this error as well, MS needs to open up on documentation on why this could happen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849729/ms-graph-rest-api-errors?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's an issue with that particular file, I still don't know why though. it's not really an answer - but the lack of documentation for anything to do with this API is stunning. I'd appreciate links.